# Stanford CoreNLP use case using Pyspark script runs fine on local node but on yarn cluster mode it runs very slow

Tags: performance, apache-spark, pyspark, stanford-nlp

I tried debugging all the possible solutions but unable to run this and scale this on cluster as i need to process 100 million records, This script runs very well on local node as expected but fails to run on Cloudera Amazon cluster. Here is the sample data that works on local node. According to me the problem is the 2 files that I am using in the udf's are not getting distributed on the executors/containers or nodes and the jobs just keeps running and processing is very slow. I am unable to fix this code to execute this on the cluster.

```
    ##Link to the 2 files which i use in the script###
    ##https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-ner-2015-12-09.zip
    ####Link to the data set########
    ##https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17b9NUonmFjp_W0dOe7nzuHr7yMM0ITTDPCBmZ6xM0iQ/edit?usp=drivesdk&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_messaging%3BQHHZFKYfTPyRb%2FmUg6ahsQ%3D%3D

    #spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 --master yarn-cluster --files /home/ec2-user/StanfordParser/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/stanford-ner.jar,/home/ec2-user/StanfordParser/stanford-ner-2016-10-31/classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz stanford_ner.py


    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    import os
    from pyspark import SparkFiles
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import Row
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
    from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

    def stanford(str):
        os.environ['JAVA_HOME']='/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/'
        stanford_classifier = SparkFiles.get("english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz")
        stanford_ner_path = SparkFiles.get("stanford-ner.jar")
        st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path, encoding='utf-8')
        output = st.tag(str.split())
        organizations = []
        organization = ""
        for t in output:
            #The word
            word = t[0]
            #What is the current tag
            tag = t[1]
            #print(word, tag)
            #If the current tag is the same as the previous tag Append the current word to the previous word
            if (tag == "ORGANIZATION"):
                organization += " " + word
            organizations.append(organization)
            final = "-".join(organizations)
            return final


    stanford_lassification = udf(stanford, StringType())

    ###################Pyspark Section###############
    #Set context
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
    sc.setLogLevel("DEBUG")
    sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

    #Get data
    df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load(r"/Downloads/authors_data.csv")

    #Create new dataframe with new column organization
    df = df.withColumn("organizations", stanford_lassification(df['affiliation_string']))

    #Save result
    df.select('pmid','affiliation_string','organizations').write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save(r"/Downloads/organizations.csv")
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, have you found any workaround for why CoreNLP is very slow when it's executed over cluster as UDF?

Comment: Yes, I redid the whole thing using pig and streaming python, could not find a  solution with spark but yes the reason seems to be because of the  slow and multiple JVM's that I call for every string or sentence,  I faced the same problem(slow and multiple JVM's at once) while using pig and streaming python, So i read the whole big files so that JVM loads once and stanford ner tags all the words in the file and then i parsed the tagged words accordingly. It will be great to get this task executed on apace spark rather than pig and streaming python

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Sunil. Do you have any benchmark? I have StanfordNLP Simple API (just sentence splitter and POS tagging) and it takes more than 2 hours for 500k scientific abstracts. I was wondering if you have some benchmarks when you change your code? Many thanks again

Comment: yes, we parsed 7 million scientific abstracts in less than 10 mins after we changed our whole approach and redid this exercise using pig and streaming python on normal 6 node cluster

Comment: Many thanks Sunil! You replies are very helpful for me to find a way to make it work on Spark. My last question to be able to compare would be, how long these 7 million abstracts took when you tried on Spark/UDF? Less than 10 minutes it's very impressive but I am just curious to know how long was it before on Spark. Once again, many thanks Sunil I really appreciate your help.